# What's the difference between superpose and superimpose?

Tags: differences, synonyms

The definitions seem very much alike:

> superposed - Place (something) on or above something else, esp. so
> that they coincide: "superposed triangles".
>
> superimpose - Place or lay (one thing) over another, typically so that both are still evident.

Are they just synonyms?

Comment: I am using the term superimposed perception (superimpositoception) to refer to the form of organism perception where neuro-electromagnetic radiation is absorbed during different flux phases from other organisms. The im- prefix was most appropriate in my use because it indicates something positioned inside an organism (as in stimulation/modulation cycle of an organism's sensory modes).

Answer (score 13):

They are synonyms but have different scopes of usage.

***Superimpose*** is the term found in [general use](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=superimpose).

***Superpose*** is used mostly in [scientific or mathematical contexts](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=superpose); see '[**superposition**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=superposition)'.

Answer (score 7):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superpose) has them as synonyms, but the difference is this:  consider the [Star of David](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David), and consider the construction of one with two solid triangles rather than interlocking triangles.

[image: Star of David]

The two triangles are *superimposed*, and both are evident.

Were one triangle not rotated, they would be *superposed*.

Comment: This is true in mathematics; in geology there is yet another usage, referring to the stratification of layers.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, so maybe I'm wrong here, but this seems unlikely to me. In this diagram, the two (implied 3-d) triangles are *interlaced*, or *interwoven*. I'd be genuinely surprised if the mathematical usage distinguished between these two words according to visibility from the particular vantage point of the observer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that is why I said _consider the construction of one with two solid triangles rather than interlocking triangles_.

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you saying that to a mathematician (are you one?) there would be two different ways of arranging the triangles (whether 2-d, 3-d, or "Escherian") such that *superimposed/superposed* unambiguously distinguishes between the two?

Comment: I am not a mathematician, nor do I play one on television.  Yes I am saying that, and the Star of David was the first commonplace geometric structure that came to mind.  I have seen Stars of David wherein it is not evident that the triangles interlock, so I wanted to make the distinction, especially after replacing my original (very large) image with an interlocking version.

Answer (score 4):

I am an American mathematician who would have liked to comment on Cornbread Ninja's answer, but I have no experience points and so am giving an "answer" instead. The variability in usage of both terms is so great that extracting a true distinction seems useless. A reading of the OED definition of each has led to me sympathize a little with Cornbread Ninja's answer.  But the 'interlacing' of the triangles in Cornbread Ninja's example seems to obfuscate the distinction being described.
The distinction is that superimposed triangles have not merged. Superposed triangles would meld together. In physics and mathematics we speak of the `superposition' of waves. For example, light is a superposition of electromagnetic waves at different frequencies. Different frequencies correspond to different colors. The colors meld together and cannot be distinguished (without a prism for example). So superposition makes sense in this context. In contrast, superimposition would be exemplified by placing pieces of colored pieces of construction paper upon one another.

Answer (score 2):

Superimposed = one image overlying another.

Superposed = the addition of one image to another, e.g. mean water level = 5mOD

Waves = +/- 1m above mean level

Superposed = water level between +4mOD and +6mOD